# add a new entry if doesn't exist in mysql table

Tags: mysql

Ok let me reframe my same question, to aim to the right output.

I have a table of below structure.

```
mysql> desc depot;
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| recd  | date     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| id    | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+

Currently I have records in the below manner.


mysql> select * from depot;
+---------------------+------+
| recd                | id   |
+---------------------+------+
| 2012-07-09          |   33 |
| 2012-07-11          |   32 |
| 2012-07-15          |   32 |
+---------------------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I need the records to print the query in the below manner, keeping the missed entries of dates of a month (say July-01 to July-31) and having 0 to the value id corresponding missed dates.

```
select < a magical query >;

+------------+------+
| recd       | id   |
+------------+------+
 2012-07-01 0
 2012-07-02 0
 2012-07-03 0
 2012-07-04 0
 2012-07-05 0
 2012-07-06 0
 2012-07-07 0
 2012-07-08 0
 2012-07-09 33
 2012-07-10 0
 2012-07-11 32
 2012-07-12 0
 2012-07-13 0
 2012-07-14 0
 2012-07-15 32
 2012-07-16 0
 2012-07-17 0
 2012-07-18 0
 2012-07-19 0
 2012-07-20 0
 2012-07-21 0
 2012-07-22 0
 2012-07-23 0
 2012-07-24 0
 2012-07-25 0
 2012-07-26 0
 2012-07-27 0
 2012-07-28 0
 2012-07-29 0
 2012-07-30 0
 2012-07-31 0
```

Comment: So why don't you just print out those dates in a loop, if you what to retrieve all dates, although they are not present in the database?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
generated_date,
COALESCE(yourTable.id, 0) AS id
FROM
(
SELECT
DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL number_days DAY) AS `generated_date` /*<-- Create dates from now back 999 days*/
FROM
(
SELECT (a + 10*b + 100*c) AS number_days FROM
  (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) aa
, (SELECT 0 AS b UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) bb
, (SELECT 0 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) cc
)sq /*<-- This generates numbers 0 to 999*/
) q
LEFT JOIN yourTable ON DATE(yourTable.datefield) = q.generated_date
WHERE q.generated_date BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(datefield) FROM yourTable) AND (SELECT MAX(datefield) FROM yourTable)
ORDER BY q.generated_date ASC
```

Comment: but my criteria is this... 1. It should start with min value and end with the max value in the tabe. 2. It should contain the timestamp column of date and time of the field for the existing columns in the table and can have any time on the missing dates in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround as it was clinging long time

BASE TABLE

```
 CREATE TABLE `deopt` (
  `recd` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Seed records to the base table

```
insert into deopt values ('2012-07-09 23:08:54',22);
insert into deopt values ('2012-07-11 23:08:54',22);
insert into deopt values ('2012-07-11 23:08:54',2222);
insert into deopt values ('2012-07-12 23:08:54',22);
insert into deopt values ('2012-07-14 23:08:54',245);
```

Create a table for dates of a month

```
CREATE TABLE seq_dates 
(
   sdate DATETIME NOT NULL,

);
```

Create a Stored Procedure to create records for a called month

```
delimiter //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_init_dates;

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_init_dates (IN p_fdate DATETIME, IN p_tdate DATETIME)
BEGIN 
DECLARE v_thedate DATETIME; 
TRUNCATE TABLE seq_dates; 
SET v_thedate = p_fdate;
WHILE (v_thedate <= p_tdate) DO 
   INSERT INTO seq_dates (sdate) 
   VALUES (v_thedate); 
   SET v_thedate = DATE_ADD(v_thedate, INTERVAL 1 DAY); 
END WHILE; 
END;

delimiter ;
```

Call the procedure for July month with starting and ending values to be seeded to seq_dates table.

```
call sp_init_dates ('2012-07-01','2012-07-31');
```

RESULT QUERY - To fetch records of all dates in a month and its corresponding ids keeping 0 inplace of null for ids.

```
select date(seq_dates.sdate),coalesce (deopt.id,0) from seq_dates LEFT JOIN deopt ON date(deopt.recd)=date(seq_dates.sdate);



+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| date(seq_dates.sdate) | coalesce (deopt.id,0) |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| 2012-07-01            |                     0 |
| 2012-07-02            |                     0 |
| 2012-07-03            |                     0 |
| 2012-07-04            |                     0 |
| 2012-07-05            |                     0 |
| 2012-07-06            |                     0 |
| 2012-07-07            |                     0 |
| 2012-07-08            |                     0 |
| 2012-07-09            |                    22 |
| 2012-07-09            |                    22 |
| 2012-07-10            |                     0 |
| 2012-07-11            |                    22 |
| 2012-07-11            |                  2222 |
| 2012-07-11            |                    22 |
| 2012-07-11            |                  2222 |
| 2012-07-12            |                    22 |
| 2012-07-13            |                     0 |
| 2012-07-14            |                   245 |
| 2012-07-15            |                     0 |
| 2012-07-16            |                     0 |
| 2012-07-17            |                     0 |
| 2012-07-18            |                     0 |
| 2012-07-19            |                     0 |
| 2012-07-20            |                     0 |
| 2012-07-21            |                     0 |
| 2012-07-22            |                     0 |
| 2012-07-23            |                     0 |
| 2012-07-24            |                     0 |
| 2012-07-25            |                     0 |
| 2012-07-26            |                     0 |
| 2012-07-27            |                     0 |
| 2012-07-28            |                     0 |
| 2012-07-29            |                     0 |
| 2012-07-30            |                     0 |
| 2012-07-31            |                     0 |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
35 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score -1):

As a two stage query:

```
SELECT @prev := null;

SELECT datefield, @prev, DATEDIFF(datefield, @prev) AS diff, @prev := datefield
FROM yourtable
HAVING diff > 1
ORDER BY datefield ASC;
```

that'll detect the dates that have a more-than-1-day difference from the previous row/date